# Google Adwords and CodeIgniter GET Variable Callback URL

Tags: codeigniter, get, google-ads-api

I am trying to implement Google Adwords with a website that has been developed using CodeIgniter, I believe it requires a "200" status code when they add a GET variable to the URL.

I've been getting emails from Google saying that it's receiving a 404 status code when it goes to my URL. When I try to add ?test=test to the end of my URL it does in fact return a 404:
[image]

Through my google searches, I have found this useful link:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/154153/#746115

Which states I need to change my config to include these:

```
$config['uri_protocol']    = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Before my uri_protocol was set to "REQUEST_URI". I have tested with ?test=test and it does work! But now all my links are not working, when I switch it to PATH_INFO, what do I need to do to fix my links?

Right now I am using Mod Rewrite to shorten the URLs so that the addresses are like mydomain.com/blog, mydomain.com/about, and my controller just points to the appropriate view. Should I not change my uri_protocol, if so how can I include a GET variable and NOT get a 404?

Any advice would help thank you!

UDPATE: Here's my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CodeIgniter 2, you can do:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, mydomain.com/?test=test now returns "An Error Was Encountered - The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." Unfortunately, the status code is still 400 according to  http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers

Comment: My permitted uri characters configuration looks like this: "$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '?a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';" I attempted to add a "?" at the beginning of this.

Comment: @Pete: Don't add '?' to permitted_uri_chars.

Comment: The good news is the links are working with this configuration

Comment: @Rocket, I have taken it out, but I'm still getting the "URL has submitted disallowed characters" error

Comment: @Pete: Try: `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=,a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`.  I think it's the `=` that was causing errors.

Comment: @Rocket, for some reason it's still telling my I have a disallowed character, could it perhaps be my .htaccess file? I can post it in the question

Comment: When I try mydomain.com/? it says disallowed char, so I think it must be the "?"

Comment: Ok well thank you so much for your help, I think I have enough to run with here

Comment: @Pete: I had this issue, but I forget how I solved it.  My config file has `$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";`, `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;`, `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`, and `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=,a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`.

Comment: @Pete: To help debugging: try adding `print_r($_SERVER)` in the `error/general.php` file.  (I think that's the right file...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following 
1- $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

2- $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-\?=&';

AND remove the "?" from your htaccess file.

3- RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]